# Add and update a column with sequential numbering based on grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with following structure

| Id | Division | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | some text |
| 2 | A | some text |
| 3 | B | some text |
| 4 | B | some text |
| 5 | B | some text |

I need to add a new column of integer type named "Order" with some data as described below:

| Id | Division | Details | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | some text | 1 |
| 2 | A | some text | 2 |
| 3 | B | some text | 1 |
| 4 | B | some text | 2 |
| 5 | B | some text | 3 |

As we can see integer data  in "Order" column sequence has to be reset if "Division" data changes.  There's are thousand of rows in the table, with more than 100 different divisions.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What happens if `'B'` changes back to `'A'`?

Comment: @Larnu, I am not sure what that mean.  But after the update there should not be any changes to data of original column (Id, Division, Details).

Comment: So once Division changes to `'B'` (in this scenario at ID `3`) you can never have another `'A'`? So what do you do at `'Z'`, what would come after?

Comment: Yes, I could have another 'A'.  
After 'Z' there could be 'A1', 'B1'... (BTW, this is not exact column names, data, I am using in the project.  The above example given just for easy understanding.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, 
    row_number() over(partition by division order by id) rn
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks.

Able to make it work using the following script,

update t
set t.Order=t.rn 
from (select mytable .*, 
    row_number() over(partition by division order by id)  rn
from mytable ) t